# PrototypeJS mouseover menu

Tags: javascript, menu, prototypejs

So i have this menu that is supposed to display submenus which are defined in object initialization by using script.aculo.us effect appear ( mouseover ) and hide them using effect fade ( mouseout from link and menu ). The problem is that i did the job with showing and hiding menus but when i get my mouse out of the link that is supposed to display it, the menu, of course, dissappears.

I'm trying to create something like the World --> Carribean --> The Cayman Islands navigation menu on this link : [click](http://www.tripwolf.com/en/guide/list/378310/The-Cayman-Islands?group=7)

If anyone has some useful links for creating menus like this one, please share. There's no point of putting my code since it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out MenuJS? http://www.menujs.net/

Comment: I implemented effects into this menu, works like a charm now. Thanks Josh